# Gradle build jar of jars

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have project A and B, both built in jenkins and pushed to artifactory.

Project C has dependencies on A and B and I can download each project's dependencies, but Gradle complains that the libraries stored in those JARs were not imported at compile time. Does anyone have an idea how to instruct Gradle to compile the libraries within the JARs?

Comment: "complains that the libraries stored in those JARs were not imported at compile time"...  Can you elaborate on this, perhaps by providing a specific error message?

Comment: Can you post you build.gradle file?

Comment: i have swagger dependency in project A.   
when i run project C in jenkins its downloads the jar file but the jar files inside jar file is not executed.

Comment: compile("com.random1:0.0.2")
  {
    changing=true
  }
  compile("com.random2:0.0.1")
  {
    changing=true
  }

Random 1 and Random 2 are diff projects. where there jar files are stored in artifacts.   When jenkins download the Random 1 and Random 2 jar files it can able to download from artifactory. but the jar files inside Random1 and Random2 are not running.

Comment: any suggestions how to unzip the jar files and execute the jars before compling the dependencies in present project

Comment: any suggestions how to unzip the jar files and execute the jars before compling the dependencies in present project